# ScrollViewReader ScrollTo notWorking

Tags: ios, swiftui, scrollview, hstack, scrollviewreader

I'm creating a horizontal menu and I'm using horizontal `ScrollView` and an `HStack` to view its items. Everything seems to work but I have a problem with `ScrollViewReader`.. As you should from the code when `currentIndex` changes I pass its value to the `proxy.scrollTo()` method but I don't get any results, the `ScrollView` does not follow the modification of `currentIndex` remaining still in its original position. Can you tell me where I'm going wrong? thank you all

```
struct ScrollableTabMenu<T:CaseIterable & Hashable & Identifiable>: View  {
    var items: [T]
    var title: KeyPath<T, String>
    @Binding var currentIndex: Int
    @Namespace private var animation
    
    var body: some View {
                  
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                HStack {
                    ForEach(items) { screen in
                        let index = items.firstIndex(of: screen)!
                        Button {
                            currentIndex = index
                        } label: {
                            Text(screen[keyPath: title])
                                .padding()
                                .overlay(alignment: .bottom){
                                    if currentIndex == index  {
                                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6)
                                            .frame(height: 1)
                                            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "AninamtionTAB", in: animation)
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                        .buttonStyle(.plain)
                    }
                }
                .onChange(of: currentIndex, { _, newValue in
                    withAnimation {
                        proxy.scrollTo(newValue, anchor: .leading)
                        print(newValue)
                    }
                })
            }
        }
        .scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)
        .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
        .contentMargins(.horizontal, 16)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scrollTo` takes the id of the view that you are scrolling to. All your buttons have the id that is automatically given by `ForEach`, which is the corresponding value of `T` in `items`, not an `Int` index number.

If you want to use the index as the id, you should add `.id(index)` to the buttons.

However, indices are rather unstable - they change whenever you add/remove a tab. I would suggest using a `Binding<T>` to represent the current tab.

```
@Binding var currentTab: T
var body: some View {
              
    ScrollView(.horizontal) {
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
            HStack {
                ForEach(items) { screen in
                    let index = items.firstIndex(of: screen)!
                    Button {
                        currentTab = screen
                    } label: {
                        Text(screen[keyPath: title])
                            .padding()
                            .overlay(alignment: .bottom){
                                if currentTab == screen  {
                                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6)
                                        .frame(height: 1)
                                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "AninamtionTAB", in: animation)
                                }
                            }
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(.plain)
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: currentTab, { _, newValue in
                withAnimation {
                    proxy.scrollTo(newValue, anchor: .leading)
                }
            })
```

Note that now you don't even need to add your own `.id(screen)` - the id that `ForEach` automatically assigns to the buttons is exactly the id that we want them to have.

Using the `.paging` scroll behaviour is rather weird in this context. The pages doesn't necessarily align with the tab buttons, so when you tap on a tab, the button gets scrolled to the left, and might get "cut off", because that happens to be where a new "page" begins.

I prefer using `.scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)`, and setting the `HStack` as the `.scrollTargetLayout()`.

I would also not use a `KeyPath<T, String>`. This doesn't allow for localisation. I would take in a `(T) -> Text` or `(T) -> Label` where `Label` is a generic type parameter constrained to `View`.

Comment: thank you tabti for your very complete and clear suggestion... you were very kind.. Your suggestions have enriched my knowledge! Thanks again!